# How do I recover the old behavior of LaTex mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex, emacs24, tex

I have happily been using emacs's LaTeX mode for years (decades?).  Up to emacs version 24.2.1, if I type C-c C-c in a LaTeX buffer that I was editting, the following would happen:

- A prompt appears in the minibuffer for me to save, which I can acknowledge by pressing y.
- A prompt appears in the minibuffer for me to latex the file, which I can acknowledge by pressing return.
- latex is run on the file in the background.  If there are no errors, a message in the minibuffer tells me so.
- If there are errors, I am prompted to press C-c ` to examine them.  This also (usually) takes me exactly to the the location of the error in the .tex file.
- Only if I press C-c C-c again without making changes to the buffer, a propmt appears in the minibuffer for me to open the .dvi in xdvi, which I can acknowledge by pressing return.

I like the above behavior.  It usually does what I want.

In 24.3.1, if I type C-c C-c in a LaTex buffer that I am editting, this is what happens:

- A prompt appears in the minibuffer for me to run xdvi.   I must type "latex" and press return.  (xdvi is already open on the file, so why would I want to open it again?)
- A prompt appears in the minibuffer for me to save, which I can acknowledge by pressing "y".
- The frame is split into two windows.  The latex command is run in a tex-shell in the bottom half.
- If the latex run was successful, I must manually remove the tex-shell window from the frame, since it is waste of screen real estate.
- If the latex run was unsuccessful, I must scroll through the tex shell buffer to see where they happened. Then I must seach the .tex manually file to find the corresponding code.

This is basically a disaster.

Is there some way to restore the old behavior?

Note: Please don't tell me to "use AUCTeX".  If I had wanted to use auctex, I would doing so by now.

Comment: `tex-mode.el` is not too extensive.  Back-up the latest version and copy over the previous version to your current installation.  If the library complains about something or other missing or wrong argument, etc., then you can deal with it -- it should be minimal.  Remember to take care of the *.gz and byte-compiled versions also.  I personally copied the entire library over to a new file and renamed everything and have spent quite a bit of time customizing it to suit my needs.

Comment: Although a little more complicated, you could always diff the two files and see what changes have been made between versions.

Comment: The behavior you describe as the one of 24.2 is not the one of plain 24.2 but the one of AUCTeX.

Comment: @Stefan That's weird.  I see no evidence I'm using auctex, or even have it loaded on 24.2 ... Emacs customization just talks about "Tex" options.

Comment: I'm not loading auctex from .emacs either ... if I've been using auctex all this time without noticing, it must be in stealth mode.

Comment: Hmm... when you hit C-c C-c, what do the various prompts you get say, *exactly*?